# How to move image in custom image view in android

Tags: android, imageview, scrollview

I have added a library to my project and it provides a custom heart shape image view but i can't move(Scroll) image in that image view. one solution that i came across is put in scroll-view but that's not working is there any code in xml so i can make image move .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="parasme.com.country.MainActivity">

    <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        >

        <ScrollView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            >


            <com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.HeartImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv32"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:src="@drawable/screenshot"
                app:siBorderWidth="8dp"
                app:siBorderColor="#585858"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                />

        </ScrollView>

    </HorizontalScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: show your code first

Answer (score 0):

Have you put the scroll view only for that image view?If so it will work,provided the image is not fit in your imageview.

```
<ScrollView
....
....>
<ImageView
width=50dp
height=60dp
.../>
</ScrollView>
```

it will work if the size of the image is greater than 50*60.If the width and height of the imageview is wrapcontent or fillparant and the size of the image is fit in that image view ,scroll will not work

Comment: is Your image fit in  your screen Shubham Chhipa?.

Comment: My image is larger than the imageview size if i try to add it by java code setBackgroundResources(R.drawable.screenshot)  it scrolls the image but the imageview is  rectangular not heart shape